# Property cannot be added as it already exists?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My error in Package Manager Console:

> The property or navigation 'MenuId' cannot be added to the entity type 'ThAmCo.Catering.Models.FoodBooking' because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'ThAmCo.Catering.Models.FoodBooking'.

I am trying to create a database for an assignment, however, I am stuck on this error.

This is my current DbContext:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThAmCo.Catering.Models
{
    public class ThAmCoContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MenuFoodItem> MenuFoodItem { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FoodBooking > FoodBooking { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Menu> Menu { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FoodItem> FoodItem { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) =>
            options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=ThAmCoCatering;");

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            // Foreign Key
            builder.Entity<MenuFoodItem>()
                .HasKey(a => new { a.MenuId, a.FoodItemId });

            builder.Entity<MenuFoodItem>()
              .HasOne(a => a.Menu)
              .WithMany(m => m.FoodItem)
              .HasForeignKey(a => a.MenuId)
              .HasForeignKey(a => a.FoodItemId);

            builder.Entity<MenuFoodItem>()
               .HasOne(a => a.FoodItem)
               .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey(a => a.FoodItemId);

            builder.Entity<FoodBooking>()
                .HasOne(m => m.Menu)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.MenuId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.Entity<FoodBooking>()
               .HasOne(a => a.Menu)
               .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey(a => a.MenuId);
        }
    }
    }
```

And this is my FoodBooking:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThAmCo.Catering.Models
{
    public class FoodBooking
    {
        public FoodBooking()
        {


        }

        [Key]
        public int FoodBookingId { get; set; }

        
        public int ClientReferenceId { get; set; }
        
        public int NumberOfGuests { get; set; }

        public Menu Menu { get; set; }
        public int MenuId { get; set; }
        
    }

}
```

This is my FoodItem class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThAmCo.Catering.Models
{
    public class FoodItem
    {
        public FoodItem()
        {
        }

        public FoodItem(int FoodItemId, string Description, float UnitPrice)
        {
            this.FoodItemId = FoodItemId;
            this.Description = Description;
            this.UnitPrice = UnitPrice;
        }

        public int FoodItemId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public float UnitPrice { get; set; }


    }
}
```

This is my Menu class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThAmCo.Catering.Models
{
    public class Menu
    {
        public Menu()
        {

        }


        public Menu(int MenuId, string MenuName)
        {

        }

        [Key]
        public int MenuId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MenuName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<MenuFoodItem> FoodItem { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is my MenuFoodItem class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThAmCo.Catering.Models
{
    public class MenuFoodItem
    {

        public MenuFoodItem()
        {

        }
        
        public MenuFoodItem(int FoodItemId, int MenuId)
        {
            this.FoodItemId = FoodItemId;
            this.MenuId = MenuId;
        }



       
        public int FoodItemId { get; set; }
        public FoodItem FoodItem { get; set; }
        
        public int MenuId { get; set; }
        public Menu Menu { get; set; }

        
    }
}
```

For context it is supposed to be for a web app that allows me to create a menu and fooditems for a venue.

Here is what the ERD should look like according to specification:
[image: ERD]

Comment: Install EF Core Power Tools and invoke its Reverse Engineer option on your existing database (or, for the more limited manual version use Scaffold-DbContext from the command line). It's the fastest, easiest way to get a DbContext and set of entities that are correctly set up for the database you have (if you don't have a database yet, create it in SSMS; it's faster and easier than shooing EF into creating it for you)

Comment: Since this is for an assignment I am not sure that this would be allowed, I could always give it a go.

Comment: Had a look and Power Tools wont work as I am using 3.1.19 EF and it isnt supported

Comment: Didn't have a problem when I tested it just now - made a new project on netcore 31, installed EF 3.1.19 and use EFCPT to reverse a db, setting the EF version to Core 3- works for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this duplicated part:

```
builder.Entity<FoodBooking>()
.HasOne(a => a.Menu)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(a => a.MenuId);
```

update this part:

```
builder.Entity<MenuFoodItem>() 
.HasOne(a => a.Menu)
.WithMany(m => m.FoodItem)
.HasForeignKey(a => a.MenuId)
.HasForeignKey(a => a.FoodItemId); 

builder.Entity<MenuFoodItem>()
.HasOne(a => a.FoodItem)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(a => a.FoodItemId);
```

to

```
builder.Entity<MenuFoodItem>()
.HasOne(a => a.FoodItem)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(a => a.FoodItemId);

builder.Entity<MenuFoodItem>()
.HasOne(a => a.Menu)
.WithMany(a => a.FoodItem)
.HasForeignKey(a => a.MenuId);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did what you said and it got rid of my error, however, now it is saying: "The relationship from 'MenuFoodItem.Menu' to 'Menu.FoodItem' with foreign key properties {'MenuId' : int, 'FoodItemId' : int} cannot target the primary key {'MenuId' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship." Im guessing that this is because I have not configured the relationship correctly?

Comment: please add the all classes to be able to answer your question

Comment: update this part

"builder.Entity<MenuFoodItem>()
.HasOne(a => a.Menu)
.WithMany(m => m.FoodItem)
.HasForeignKey(a => a.MenuId)
.HasForeignKey(a => a.FoodItemId);

builder.Entity<MenuFoodItem>()
.HasOne(a => a.FoodItem)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(a => a.FoodItemId);"

to
builder.Entity<MenuFoodItem>()
.HasOne(a => a.FoodItem)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(a => a.FoodItemId);

builder.Entity<MenuFoodItem>()
.HasOne(a => a.Menu)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(a => a.MenuId);

Comment: Hello thanks for that but it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240490/discussion-between-kerollos-melad-and-vortex).